Looking for an Aliens novel (not graphic) in which Newt and Hicks (an android) are dating
I vividly remember Newt and Hicks dating and Ripley(?) Not being happy with this as Hicks was an android. I suspect there was plenty of alien killing too, but remember nothing of what happened.
I read this ~20 years ago. It's not part of the main aliens book series as that follows the films and they both die. I also remember it not being a graphic novel at that time.
The title and author would be great, as I'd like to read it again.

Welcome to Literature Stack Exchange, take our [tour]! Please read our identification-request wiki and, if any of the prompts there jog your memory, please [edit] your question with more details. For example, was this an "official" book or something made by a fan? It wasn't a graphic novel, but do you remember the cover design? Were their chapters images? Approximately how large (cover area & book thickness/length) was this book? What age range was it aimed at? What language was it in? Every bit helps.

Are you sure this wasn't a graphic novel? It sounds a bit like "Aliens: Book One", except that Newt dates an android marine called Butler, and it is Hicks who disapproves.

Can't be 100% sure. It was a long time ago. Have ordered the graphic novel. Maybe it'll be familiar. Thanks

Ah! I've just discovered there was a novelization of "Aliens: Book One", by Steve Perry, called "Aliens: Earth Hive". That could be it, except that to avoid continuity clashes with Alien 3, some character names were changed ("Hicks" and "Newt" become "Wilks" and "Billie").

@munkykisser Don't forget to let us know if the novel is what you were looking for  ;)

I got the graphic novel and that's exactly it, but a novelisation. I must have read an older version as the names were Newt and Hicks and it was deffo Bishop she dated. Thank you!

Short answer: I think that the Aliens novel that the OP is looking for could be Aliens: Earth Hive by Steve Perry, although it does not involve Ripley, and the names of the characters were altered - "Hicks" becomes "Wilks" and "Newt" becomes "Billie" - to avoid continuity clashes with the movies. In the novel Hicks acted as a parent figure to Newt, and disapproved of her falling in love with a marine under his command, who is later revealed to actually be an android (although neither he nor Newt knew this at the time). This roughly fits the main points in the question.
This is actually a novelization of an earlier graphic novel
Aliens: Book One by Mark Verheiden. This was published by Dark Horse Comics over 1988-1989, in the interval between the release of Aliens and Alien 3. Following her rescue in Aliens, Newt has been committed to a mental institution to treat her (understandable) psychological problems, while Hicks has been selected to train a group of marines to tackle a new Alien menace.
Newt's behavior becomes ever more erratic, and so Hicks decides to rescue her from the asylum and take her with him on the mission, so that she can face her fears. On the trip she becomes romantically attached to one of the marines, Butler - a relationship which Hicks thoroughly disapproves of. In battle with the aliens, Butler is ripped in half, revealing him to actually be a synthetic lifeform (an android). In fact all the marines on the mission, were androids except for Hicks, but none of them knew this.

The novelisation of this comic, Aliens: Earth Hive, was released in 1992. I have not read this, but the wikipedia summary seems to indicate that it follows the plot of the comic quite closely. As it was released after Aliens 3, however, the names of the characters were changed to avoid continuity issues with the movie franchise.
